# Node Redis-- Aggregate on Search

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, aggregate-functions, node-redis

How to use the Redis OM for node to perform aggregate operation on the search results returned?

I have the following code to search the redis DB

let data =  await client.ft.search('idx:schemaTest1', `@${key}:${value}`)

I expect the data to be an array of objects and wants to convert it to an array of nested objects based on some condition.

Comment: Did you check the `aggregate` function? See: https://redis.io/commands/ft.aggregate/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are we talking about Redis OM for Node.js here or Node Redis? The proffered code and title reference Node Redis while the first sentence specifically cites Redis OM. For clarity, Redis OM is an object mapping layer on top of Node Redis. Node Redis is a low-level client that wraps Redis commands—like `FT.SEARCH` or `FT.AGGREGATE`.

Comment: I meant the Redis OM. Thank you for the clarification.